# ¿como puedo saber cuales fechas expiraron y cuales estan vigentes en una consulta de mysql?

Tags: mysql

como puedo hacer una query en donde quiero saber que documento ya va a expirar, ya que cuando dan de alta a un abogado ingresan la fecha de registro del abogado y la fecha que expira un documento que traen como representante de la empresa, pero cuando yo muestro la tabla de abogados registrados pues me aparecen todos, pero hay una manera de que en esa consulta en donde muestro todos los abogados dados de alta sepa cuales fechas ya van a expirar??
[image: esta es mi tabla de abogados]

Comment: Pon un ejemplo para que se te entienda mejor, y ademas pon la consulta que tienes hecha hasta ahora

Comment: ¿Cuál es el criterio para considerar que *"ya van expirar"*? ¿Un mes, una semana, 3 días, 12 horas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quiero suponer que buscas una query que solo muestre los documentos que van a vencer **días** antes de que lo hagan asi que:

```
SELECT [registros que requiera seleccionar además de la fecha],fechaVigencia FROM [nombre de tu tabla] WHERE DATEDIFF(fechaVigencia,now()) = 4 AND NOT DATEDIFF(fechaVigencia,now()) <= 0;
```

**Explicación:**

El número (en este caso 4) que tiene el primer WHERE representa el número de días en los que el documento este apunto de vencer.

si es que ya expiro, la consulta **no lo mostrara**. Para que se muestren también las ya vencidas, solo borre el segundo AND.

Espero pueda ayudarte esta consulta.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio tu comentario te agradezco mucho